# How to calculate resistance in LED project with the goal of extending battery life

Tags: resistance

I'm converting a kerosene lantern to battery-powered LEDs, loosely based on an Instructables project. It uses 4AA batteries (6 volts) and 2 LEDs wired parallel, and 470-ohm resistors.

The yellow flickering 5mm LEDs I purchased are rated as follows: Forward Voltage : 3.0V-3.2V ; Forward Current: 20mA. (I can't find the voltage drop per se, but I'm assuming it's about 2.1 V).

The author of the Instructables project says this setup maximizes battery life. I believe I could use 220-ohm resistors instead of the 470-ohm resistors, and this would provide more power to the LEDs, but at the expense of battery life. Is that correct?

Also, if I added a third LED to this setup (so 6 volts, 3 LEDs, and 3 470-ohm resistors), I'm guessing battery life will be somewhat decreased but still be pretty good because I'm using more resistance than strictly necessary? In short, I'm trying to better understand the role of resistance in electronic circuits, especially if the goal is maximize battery life. Thank you.

Comment: "I can't find the voltage drop" - the forward voltage at 20mA is given in the rating you provided as 3V-3.2V. Are you sure they are stated as wired in parallel as opposed to series?

Comment: You can nearly double your battery life in this case if you use a buck constant current driver instead of resistors.

Comment: I don't know anything about a buck constant current driver. Can you tell me exactly what I'm looking for? It would have to be something for 6 volts, 20 mAs.

Comment: You should add a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe I could use 220-ohm resistors instead of the 470-ohm
> resistors, and this would provide more power to the LEDs, but at the
> expense of battery life. Is that correct?

Yes, LEDs are brighter with 220 ohms rather than 470 ohms, but drain the battery faster. Be aware that LED brightness is very nearly proportional to current through them, and current is also what drains batteries.

You might consider this arrangement with two LEDs in series. Unfortunately, a 6V battery isn't enough to get consistent LED current to flow (a depleted ^V battery won't light two series-connected LEDs, or perhaps make them quite dim).
Adding a 5th battery gives that little extra headroom to get LED current flowing. Note that the series resistor drops to 55 ohms. This ballast resistor soaks up battery voltage that would otherwise over-drive the LEDs. Its smaller value wastes less battery power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB9AjC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This series arrangement wastes less battery power than parallel LEDs. I consider power dissipated by the resistor as "wasted" since it puts out heat rather than light. Wasted power: \$ I^2\times R1\$
If you consider this 20mA LED current too bright, increase value of R1.

---

R1 is determined by first estimating how much current flows (and hence, how much LED light is produced). Current is the same through D1, D2, R1.
For this example, 20 mA is the desired current. Since the two series-connected LEDs use up 6.4 volts of the 7.5V battery, the remaining voltage appears across R1. Then \$R1= {{(7.5-6.4)}\over{20mA}} = 55 ohms\$

Comment: I'll try this out on the breadboard, but I'll have to order some more resistors. How did you arrive at the 55 ohms?

Comment: An edit added showing how R1 is determined. I've assumed worst-case LED voltage of 3.2V. Apparently, LED voltage could be as low as 3.0V at 20mA (which would make R1 larger than 55 ohms)

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.

Comment: Using 5 cells each cell may be discharged until the voltage is lower than 1.28 V. With 6 cells 1.066 V is possible and the lamp will light even longer.

Answer (score 1):

> The author of the Instructables project says this setup maximizes battery life. I believe I could use 220-ohm resistors instead of the 470-ohm resistors, and this would provide more power to the LEDs, but at the expense of battery life. Is that correct?

Yes.  Your LEDs are 3.0 to 3.2V.  I will assume 3.0V at low currents.  With a 6V battery, minus 3V for the LED, gives about 3V across teh resistor. 3/470 = 6.4mA.  That's quite a small current.

With two LEDs, that gives you about 12.8mA.  Add a third and it's 19.2mA.

> In short, I'm trying to better understand the role of resistance in electronic circuits, especially if the goal is maximize battery life.

The resistor limits the current.  All LEDs should have something limiting the current through them.  The higher the resistor, the less current flows.  That's Ohm's law, I = V/R (current = volts / ohms).

Answer (score 1):

To best extend the battery life, consider sourcing the best LEDs you can find. Novelty LEDs may not use the highest efficiency LED dies so you'll be wasting power on that account.

Given a set of LEDs with just resistors you have a straightforward trade-off of battery life vs. brightness. Maybe consider having a switch with several brightness levels (via several resistors) so the appropriate brightness can be selected.

Finally, you have the option of various more sophisticated switchmode drivers, which can perhaps double the battery life (or provide equivalent battery life with fewer cells). I suggest searching 'backlight drivers'. Many will be designed to operate from a single Li-ion cell (3.7V) but there is a wide range available.

There is a somewhat subtle difference between using just a resistor and a switchmode circuit. The former will provide progressively dimmer light as the battery is drained, the latter may suddenly shut down (or misbehave) after providing full brightness for the life of the battery. Not a big deal if it's a decoration, but if you're depending on a flashlight to get you down a wilderness trail after dark you might prefer the graceful dimming result.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to achieve maximum efficiency, a simple buck converter will likely be your best option. The [HV9919B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/20005462B-1021785.pdf) is less than a dollar, has a typical efficiency of about 90%, and provides a way to obtain a wide range of dimming with just a potentiometer.

There are also [some switching converters](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps92560.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1686972851185&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.com%252F) that can run in buck or boost mode, so you can drive a string of multiple LEDs from a 6V supply (or even less).